# MudBlazor MudSelect validation

Tags: validation, drop-down-menu, mudblazor

I have a simple MudBlazor MudSelect list

```
   <MudSelect T="int" Label="Choose Coverage Type" 
              AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter" Variant="Variant.Outlined"
              Margin="Margin.Dense" For="@(() => newLink.CoverageType)">
         <MudSelectItem Value="0">No Coverage Selected</MudSelectItem>
         <MudSelectItem Value="1">Auto</MudSelectItem>
         <MudSelectItem Value="2">Cyber</MudSelectItem>
         <MudSelectItem Value="3">D&O/EPL</MudSelectItem>
         <MudSelectItem Value="4">General Liability</MudSelectItem>
         <MudSelectItem Value="5">General Risk Management</MudSelectItem>
         <MudSelectItem Value="6">Property</MudSelectItem>
       </MudSelect>
```

In my class I have DataAnnotations for validation

```
        //[RegularExpression ("^[1-6]$", ErrorMessage="A Coverage Type is Required")]
        [Required]
        public int CoverageType { get; set; }
```

I can get validation working on simple textboxes, but I want a validation error if the first item in the dropdown is slected "No Coverage Selected"

Does anyone know how to do this with the MudBlazor control?  I have not found anything on their website.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Yes I got this working by using a regex  on the property to make sure a value was selected that is > 0.  The code is the same as above but uncommented of course and the regex I used is "^[1-9][0-9]*$" 
Hopefully this helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try validating the field using the [`MudForm`](https://mudblazor.com/components/form) component.

### Example:

https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QYQcaMkIrMqCiOQf

```
@using System.Text.RegularExpressions
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<MudForm @ref="form" class="my-3">
    <MudSelect
            T="int"
            Label="Choose Coverage Type" 
            AnchorOrigin="Origin.BottomCenter"
            Variant="Variant.Outlined"
            Margin="Margin.Dense"
            For="@(() => newLink.CoverageType)">
        <MudSelectItem Value="0">No Coverage Selected</MudSelectItem>
        <MudSelectItem Value="1">Auto</MudSelectItem>
        <MudSelectItem Value="2">Cyber</MudSelectItem>
        <MudSelectItem Value="3">D&O/EPL</MudSelectItem>
        <MudSelectItem Value="4">General Liability</MudSelectItem>
        <MudSelectItem Value="5">General Risk Management</MudSelectItem>
        <MudSelectItem Value="6">Property</MudSelectItem>
    </MudSelect>
</MudForm>

<MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="@(()=>form.Validate())">Validate</MudButton>
<MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Error" OnClick="@(()=>form.Reset())">Reset</MudButton>
<MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" OnClick="@(()=>form.ResetValidation())">Reset Validation</MudButton>

@code {
    private YourModel newLink = new YourModel();
    private MudForm form;

    class YourModel
    {
        [RegularExpression ("^[1-6]$", ErrorMessage="A Coverage Type is Required")]
        [Required]
        public int CoverageType { get; set; }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  After looking at the documentation again, it looks like if you used EditForm you use DataAnnotations, but for MudForm you use the validation properties.  I will have to do some testing with a MudForm